# how to realize Android Camera Focusing (Continuous) like a Built-in Camera

Tags: java, android, camera, autofocus

I've made Camera App like Built-in Camera.

I want to implement function that continuous focusing like a  Built-in Camera's it.
(this function what i do not touch screen but camera try to focusing itself. )

So, Setting this where surfaceCreated :

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

and called Method :

```
private void setAutoFocusMoveCallback(Camera camera, AutoFocusMoveCallback cb)
{
    System.out.println("setAutoFocusMoveCallback : Check  " + cb.toString());
    mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
    camera.setAutoFocusMoveCallback(cb);
}
```

but this method is not work on Samsung Galaxy S4, S5, Note3.
but another smart phone worked!

So, I want to find another method!
(um... I do not understand why Samsung Galaxy S4, S5, Note3 is not work.. )

Please help me.
please coach another method :)

Comment: Samsung has done lots of customizations. You can print out all parameters to see what focus mode does Samsung's device support. And try different focus modes to verify the effect. The standard hardware APIs can not guarantee the same effect for different devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO seem not working properly on Samsung latest devices, such as S5, however, it could use FOCUS_MODE_AUTO and manually trigger setAutofocus by sensor changes, touches, or brightness changes.

Comment: I've also noticed that FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE does not work properly for S5, is this a known issue? Where did you find that information?

Comment: @bcorso I didn't find that information, but I did tests on around 10 different phones. FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE are all working perfect on Nexus 4&5, HTC series, Sony devices, even Samsung S3, but just not for S5. S5 sometimes stays at blur state and won't focus. I ended up with using FOCUS_MODE_AUTO and it works perfect on all devices.

Comment: I also tried to use `FOCUS_MODE_AUTO`. I was able to get touch to focus on the touched area to work well for the S5 but not for the S4. Conversely, `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` works well for S4 but not S5... kind of frustrating.

Comment: @bcorso Actually, I didn't test on S4. I am surprising that FOCUS_MODE_AUTO doesn't work on S4. I tested S3 and it works on different parameters. For the temporary solution, you may add special logic ,such as "String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;", to set FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE for galaxy s4 only.

Comment: @bcorso Also you could try to raise the question on Samsung developer forum at http://developer.samsung.com/forum/en.

Comment: FYI I found this http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=223500 which basically means you will have to handle the discrepancy in behavior yourself because Samsung is saying this is expected behavior.

Comment: Update: FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE is actually working for me if I am delaying the param setting by 500ms. See this thread (very bottom): 
http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/a/201/251813

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks about the Samsung S5 focus feature:

- When using AUTO focus mode: setting focus area directly after preview start didn't work for me, I had to call setFocusAreas() and setMeteringAreas() in a delayed Runnable (250 ms)
- when using CONTINUOUS_PICTURE: I wanted to start an auto focus when user taps on screen. So on touch event I set focus mode to AUTO, and call autofocus(). I had to reset focusAreas and FocusMeteringAreas (just call setfocusAreas(null) and setMeteringAreas(null)) before setting back CONTINUOUS_PICTURE focus mode to get continuous focus back again after autofocus.

Also note that continuous focus is ignoring focus and metering areas, it's only focusing on the objects at the center of the screen..

I observed this behaviour only on Samsung S5.. (tested on S5 neo, S6, S7, XPeria E5, Nexus 5, Wiko UFeel and ASUS ZenPhone2)